# UIActivityViewController is not being dismissed - ios (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, dismiss

I'm having problems with a customized UIActivity for sharing in iOS.

I have an activityViewController called avc, and I call it this way in my main controller:

`[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:^{[self animationCompleted];}];`

and then I have my animationCompleted function:

```
-(void)animationCompleted{

//-- define the activity view completion handler
avc.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){

    if (completed) {
        if ([activityType isEqualToString: @"myType"]){

            otherController = [[OtherController alloc] init];
            [self presentModalViewController:otherController animated:YES];

        }
    } 
};
```

}

The problem I'm having is that when I try to present my otherController I get a warning telling me that I'm trying to present a UIViewController while another is presenting or dismissing (I have debugged and it seems like UIActivityViewController is not dismissed).

The documentation says that completionHandler is called when the UIActivityViewController is dismissed, so why am I getting this error??

Thank you very much.